# How to open files with variable date name in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open file names with different dates and format, pull certain worksheets and compile them into one separate workbook together.

I've tried using Format(Date, ".....) see code

```
  Windows("Comparison NAV_ Fund Summary_" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Comparison NAV- Fund Summary").Select
    Sheets("Comparison NAV- Fund Summary").Copy After:=Workbooks("CurrentNew.xls" _
        ).Sheets(1)
```

With this section, I'm getting the

> "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range"

when I try to run the code.

As reference, I'm trying to open the file with the name: 
"Comparison NAV_ Fund Summary_mm-dd-yyyy.xlsx"

Comment: Are the workbooks you are trying to copy from and copy to open?

Comment: Yes, everything is already open, and it  works if it put the actual date in instead of the Format(date,...)

Comment: Are the names of the files using today's current date?

Comment: the files being opened are opened every business day, and are all coming in the same format of mm-dd-yyyy after the "_" in the filename

Comment: Well Date returns the current date, the format of the date is the string - "mm-dd-yyyy" so if the dates are not the same as today's date it won't find the file, you would need an input box or something.